# Drawing energy from a 3.7V LiPo battery while simultaneously charging with a solar panel

Tags: solar-cell, energy, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a 200mAh 3.7V (0.7W) LiPo battery that I am looking to use as an energy source for a large model airship.

I also have a 7.2V 100mA (0.72W) solar panel that I would like to use as a means of topping off the battery's charge when necessary to allow for a longer flight duration.

I am wondering, because this will need to provide a constant supply of energy, what the best approach might be to integrate the solar panel into the system.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Leave the solar panel at home and worry first about getting the airship to work at all.  If you accomplish that, then you can start to think about future developments that would likely only make sense in the context of a much larger aircraft flying multi-day "missions".

Comment: you cannot charge a battery that is being discharged ... it is like trying to run water through a pipe in opposite directions at the same time

Comment: @jsotola You can, however, charge a battery and power a load from the same solar cell if it has enough output

Comment: @DKNguyen that is correct ... the comment is a response to the title of the post

Comment: @jsotola I know. OP is looking at things the wrong way. You can also power part of a load with the solar cell and have the battery make up the rest such that the solar cell assists the battery so the battery drains more slowly, if the solar cell is not powerful enough to power the load on its own.

Comment: @Chris Stratton That was originally the plan, however my calculations have already shown that the craft will indeed work. The idea I am hoping to put forth with this prototype is whether it would work at a small scale, because that is what my budget allows; it is my belief that if it works at a small scale, it would have the potential to be scalable.

Comment: I doubt the applicability of your calculations, but you can try flying the airship with the panel as dead weight.  And you can measure the power output of the panel under reasonably representative conditions.  Given you haven't built and flow the airship yet and so are overlooking many issues both imaginable and unanticipated, worrying about the charging circuit at this stage is putting the cart before the horse.  Also, um, *wind*...

Comment: @jsotola I guess you don't charge your car battery while driving because of water through the pipe.

Comment: @Moty, of course you charge the battery while driving a fuel powered car ... you also charge batteries in an electric car when rolling downhill

Comment: _my calculations have already shown that the craft will indeed work_ ... Sometimes (only sometimes, of course), calculations fail. Do as @ChrisStratton said: first get your prototype working with a previously charged battery. Start with this topping solar charger only after that.

Comment: @mguima I appreciate your feedback, and yes, I am starting to think that that is without a doubt the best course of action; that way I can work more on how it will be secured to the top of the envelope, how its wiring will reach the battery, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect the solar panel to the battery permanently and add a circuit that switches the charge current off when the voltage on the battery reaches 4.2V

Comment: No. That is **NOT** how you charge a lithium battery.  It's also not a very good way to use a solar cell.